# Sum of all the elements in a Vector Java

Tags: java

Java 11.6

I have a vector of size 8, where depending on the user input of a number between 1 to 8, my code will randomly generate values to place in a vector called vec_1.

So, for example, the output would look like

```
Enter the number of trials: 
>> 4 
Trials    Random Value
1           10
2           20
3            0
4           60
```

The values <10,20,0,60> are saved in the vector  called vec_1 and then I used

```
Enumeration enu = vec_tor.elements();
while(enu.hasMoreElements()) {
   for (int i = 1; i<=4; i++) {
     System.out.printf("\n     " + String.valueOf(i));
     System.out.printf("      " + String.valueOf(enu.nextElement()));
   }
 }
```

to print out the elements from the vector side by side. I would like to add all the numbers in the vector together to get a sum so 10+20+0+60 = 90. I want to print "Sum: 90" after adding every element of the vector.  I am not sure how to add element by element for a vector in java and I tried looking up other questions but they are mostly related to arrays. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Vector` is deprecated, avoid using it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Java Streams API:

```
int sum = test.stream()
    .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf) // or .map(i -> i)
    .sum();
```

Explanation:

- `test` is a `Vector<Integer>`.
- Classes implementing `java.util.Collection` must implement the `stream` method. This enables the programmer to use the Stream API. `Vector` also implements `Collection`.
- `mapToInt` is a method which causes all elements pulled from the stream to be mapped to the primitive `int`. This is represented by the `IntStream` class. We map `Integer` to just the corresponding `int`, either by doing `i -> i` (by auto-unboxing) or by `Integer::valueOf`.
- `IntStream` implements a `sum()` method, which is exactly what we need.

Answer (score 2):

Vector elements sum:

```
Integer sum = v.stream()    // convert to stream
  .reduce(0,Integer::sum);  // add all elements to initial zero value
```

Array from vector:

```
Integer [] a = v.toArray(new Integer[0]); // vector to array
```

Unit test

```
package example;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class VectorSumTest {
    @Test
    public void sumVector() {
        Integer [] data = {10,20,0,60};
        Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(data));
        Integer sum = v.stream().reduce(Integer::sum).get(); // vector elements sum
        assertThat(sum, equalTo(90));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add elements calling `add()` on the vector itself. Then you can use a `stream()` to add all the elements and return the total sum.

```java
import java.util.*;

class VectorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Integer> vec_tor = new Vector<>(); 

        vec_tor.add(10); 
        vec_tor.add(20); 
        vec_tor.add(0); 
        vec_tor.add(60); 

        System.out.println(vec_tor);

        int sum = vec_tor.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
        System.out.println("Sum of vector elements: " + sum);
    }
}
```

The code above will output:

```
[10, 20, 0, 60]
Sum of vector elements: 90
```

Here is the documentation on [Vector.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add(E)) and [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) if you want to investigate a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do it

```
    // using iterator
    Iterator<Integer> it = vec_tor.iterator();
    int sum = 0;
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        sum+=it.next();
    }
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);

    // using enumeration
    sum = 0;
    Enumeration<Integer> enumeration = vec_tor.elements();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
        sum+=enumeration.nextElement();
    }
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);

    // using simple foreach loop
    for (int element: vec_tor) {
        sum += element; 
    }
    System.out.println("sum:" + sum);
```

You can use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` here as `Vector` is a pretty old data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();
    // add elements

    long sum = 0;
    for (Integer x : vector) {
        sum += x; // sum = sum + x;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

The for loop just iterates through every element. No need for the complicated enumeration structure. It also respects the actual element count stored in the Vector.

Note: Vector is a pretty old data structure. Nowadays usually a `List` like `ArrayList` is used.

Comment: thank you and thank you as well for suggesting ArrayList, I am still new to java and programming in general, so learning everything from scratch

Comment: Vector implements the List interface too. The reason why one would prefer ArrayList over Vector is because methods in Vector are synchronized. The synchronization adds an extra performance hit and often the synchronization implementation of individual methods does not meet the programmer's needs and a separate synchronization mechanism needs to be implemented anyway.